# Recycler view show blank items

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I'm building an android app that searches a string from sqlite db and display the result in recyclerview.

The problem that I found building this app is when I type f.e a string containing the letter "a", it display the number of lines that contain the letter as blank items. Can anyone help please?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void fetchContactOffline(String flcode) {
        ArrayList<QueryResult> list = new ArrayList();
        if (flcode.length() > 0) {
            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder("select * from ").append(TABLE_NAME).append(" where ");
            query.append(TABLE_COLUMN_FLCODE).append(" like \"%").append(flcode).append("%\"");
            SQLiteOpenHelper database = new RichDB(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = database.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query.toString(), null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    QueryResult queryResult = new QueryResult();
                    queryResult.answer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_COLUMN_ANSWER));
                    queryResult.question = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TABLE_COLUMN_QUESTION));
                    list.add(queryResult);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            db.close();
        }
        progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
        adapter = new Adapter(list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**Adapter.java**
```

```
private ArrayList<QueryResult> questions;

public Adapter(ArrayList<QueryResult> questions) {
    this.questions = questions;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.reponse.setText(questions.get(position).getAnswer());
    holder.reponse.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    holder.question.setText(questions.get(position).getQuestion());
    holder.question.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return questions.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView reponse,question;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        reponse = itemView.findViewById(R.id.AnswerItem);
        question = itemView.findViewById(R.id.QuestionItem);
    }
}
```

```
<br>
**items.xml**
<br>
```

```
<TextView
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#111"
    android:id="@+id/AnswerItem"
    android:text="Answer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/QuestionItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:text="Question" />

<View
    android:background="#bfbfbf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.1dp"/>
```

```
**ScreenCapture**
[Screenshot - 1][1]

[Screenshot - 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtnHq.png)

Comment: can you also provide you layout xml?

Comment: Show this class `QueryResult `.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is that you don't call this:
`recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager (this));`.
And I think that this line - `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` is excessive, because new instance of adapter was created two lines above - `adapter = new Adapter(list);`

Comment: I have ```recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager (this));``` before i call the function fetchcontactoffline , the problem is that the rows(items) does show up but blank !!

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed it , the problem was in the **QueryResult.java**. thank you for your help . :)